# Jira Groovy script in script runner

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm trying to get users not in the jira-users group with email addresses not equal to: email@email.com. I can get the users not in the jira-users group(see below) but not sure how to complete the if statement to show "users email address not equal to email@email.com. I tried user.getEmail but couldn't get that to work. Would someone be able to make a suggestion with this?

Thanks.

```
 for ( user in crowdService.search(query) ) { 
  if (!crowdService.isUserMemberOfGroup(user.getName(), "jira-users")) {
   body = body + user.getName() + "\n"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The User object implementation [depends](http://www.opensymphony.com/osuser/api/com/opensymphony/user/User.html) [on](http://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-crowd/2.1.0/com/atlassian/crowd/integration/model/user/User.html) [your](http://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-crowd/2.1.0/com/atlassian/crowd/embedded/api/User.html) particular Atlassian setup.

Try calling `user.getEmailAddress()`:

```
for ( user in crowdService.search(query) ) { 
    if (!crowdService.isUserMemberOfGroup(user.getName(), "jira-users") 
            && !user.getEmailAddress().equals("email@email.com")) {
        body = body + user.getName() + "\n"
    }
}
```